# What hydrocarbons burn in air without a change in volume?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Find all hydrocarbons(alkanes, alkynes, alkenes), which answers given conditions:

the sum of volumes of combustion air products equals to the initial sum of volumes of airs. ( volumes are measured in the same conditions 101.3 kPa pressure and 150 deg C)

So this is my solution:  let's write ideal air equation --> we get $PV=nRT$  therefore for the same conditions volumes are dependent on the moles.

So next I wrote general equations for combustion of every type of hydrocarbons.

Next I summed coefficients of products and equated to the sum of the coefficients of reagents.

For example for alkanes, we get  $(3n+1)/2 + 1 =n$  this doesn't have a solution in positive numbers so these kinds of hydrocarbons don't exist.

Comment: The reasoning is right, the math isn't.

Comment: Write the chemical formula for the complete combustion of an alkane then show the math formula which proves that after burning that alkane using an isothermal process that the volume must increase.

Comment: repeat steps for alkane using simplest alkene and alkyne. What happens?

Comment: Ok, the compound has to be a gas at 150 C, so the boiling point has to be lower than that. Write down the reaction for complete combustion of n-alkanes (methane, ethane, propane, butane, pentane) can you see a pattern in how many molecules on left and how many on right? Mathematical formula for pattern? // Remember isomers. So if butane would work so would isobutane. However the reverse is also true. If butane doesn't work then isobutane can't work either.

Comment: Earn some cred on the site. Write the chemicals reactions and the math formula in answer. -- You can answer your own questions here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we consider a possibly branched, but not cyclical  hydrocarbon ( unless we count each cycle as an extra double bond ):

$$\ce{C_nH_{2n+2-2d-4t}},$$

where

- d is number of double bonds
- t is number of triple bonds

then the combustion reaction is

$$\ce{C_nH_{2n+2-2d-4t}} + (n + 0.5(n + 1 - d - 2t))\ce{ O2 -> n CO2 } + (n+1-d-2t)\ce{H2O}$$

Comparing volumes, we get:

$$1 + 1.5n + 0.5(1 - d - 2t)=n + (n + 1-d-2t)$$

$$0.5(1 - d - 2t)=0.5n - d -2t$$

$$n=1 + d + 2t $$

With the restriction $$n \gt d + t$$

For alkanes (d=0, t=0): n=1, so $\ce{CH4}$.

For simple alkenes (d=1, t=0): n=2, so $\ce{CH2=CH2}$. For longer chain, the would have to be cumulated double bonds: $\ce{CH2=Cn=CH2}$

For simple alkynes (d=0, t=1): n=3, so $\ce{CH3-C#CH}$, $\ce{HC#C-CH2-C#CH}$ etc.

Answer (score 7):

We can more simply render the hydrocarbon as $\ce{C_xH_y}$.  Render the combustion reaction

$\ce{C_xH_y + O2 -> CO2 + H2O}$

and balance the equation:

$\ce{C_xH_y + (x +\frac{y}{4}) O2 -> x CO2 + \frac{y}{2} H2O}$

Combustion takes place in the vapor phase and, from the Ideal Gas Law, the volume of the reactants or products will be proportional to the total number of moles of gas once the combustion products are brought to the same temperature and pressure as the reactants.  So equate the number of moles on both sides:

$1+x +\frac{y}{4}=x+\frac{y}{2}$

from which $x$ cancels out and we can solve for $y=4$.

Thus any hydrocarbon gas with four hydrogen atoms per molecule burns at constant number of moles of gas, which leads to constant volume once the combustion products are brought to the same temperature and pressure as the reactants.  Methane and ethene are the most common such hydrocarbons, but some others that remain gaseous with more carbon atoms are also possible.

Comment: Good answer  :-)  I have not realized that count 4.